SwiftData deletion of the child's child element is complicated
I have a model, where 1 Meter has many Rates, and each Rate has many Readings.
So I would like to do a delete button for 1 of the Readings. But in a view I show Readings through the extension, which does some transformations.
So, the view works as expected, but I just do not understand, how to implement delete button:
Here's the view itself:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct MeterDetailView: View {
    
    // The meter object associated with this view
    let meter: Meter

    // Access to the SwiftData model context, used for performing actions like saving or deleting data
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    var body: some View {
        
        // The main navigation stack for the view
        NavigationStack {
            // A list that displays sections of rates and readings
            List {
                // Check if the meter has any associated rates
                if let rates = meter.rates {
                    // Sort the rates by their order property
                    let sortedRates = rates.sorted(by: { $0.order < $1.order })
                    
                    // Loop through each rate and create a section for it
                    ForEach(sortedRates) { rate in
                        Section(rate.name) {
                            // Check if the rate has any associated readings
                            if rate.readings != nil {
                                // Sort the readings by date, in descending order (most recent first)
                                let readings = rate.readings!.sorted(by: { $0.date > $1.date })
                                
                                // Loop through the readings and display each one using ExtendedReadingView
                                // The `paddedReadingDigits()` method provides the necessary data for display
                                ForEach(readings.paddedReadingDigits(), id: \.0.self) { (reading, paddedDigits, difference) in
                                    ExtendedReadingView(extendedReading: (reading: reading, paddedReading: paddedDigits, difference: difference))
                                        .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                                            // Swipe action for deleting a reading
                                            Button {
                                                // Action for deleting the reading (functionality to be implemented)
                                            } label: {
                                                // The button is labeled "Delete" with a trash icon
                                                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                                                    .tint(.red) // Set the button color to red
                                            }
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // If no rates are found, display a message to the user
                    Text("No rates found for this meter")
                        .foregroundColor(.red) // Set the message color to red
                }
            }
        }
        // Set the navigation bar title to display the meter's name and the associated home's name
        .navigationBarTitle("\(meter.name) \(meter.home.name)")
    }
    
    // Function to delete a reading, which will be implemented to remove the reading from the data model
    func deleteReading(reading: Reading) {
        // Implementation needed to delete the reading from the model context
    }
}

and here is the extension, which calculates some data:
extension Array where Element == Reading {
    func paddedReadingDigits() -> [(Reading, String, Int?)] {
        // Find the maximum number of digits in the readingDigits values
        let maxWidth = self.map { String($0.readingDigits).count }.max() ?? 0
        
        // Iterate through the array and calculate the padded digits and differences
        return self.enumerated().map { index, reading in
            let paddedReading = String(format: "%0\(maxWidth)d", reading.readingDigits)
            let difference: Int? = index < self.count - 1 ? reading.readingDigits - self[index + 1].readingDigits : nil
            return (reading, paddedReading, difference)
        }
    }
}

